# Stack Overflow - Code Review Overlap Questions

Tags: discussion

I came across [a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290182/is-there-a-problem-with-this-script) which — perhaps aside from the title — seems to be appropriate for SO *and* CR (according to both FAQs).

**OP’s Question**

> I am not php/javascript expert, so can anyone tell me if this is good
>   or not and if it will fail under some conditions?

The OP’s code is *working* code and the question is requesting *critique* (at least that’s how I read it). It was asked and answered on SO with no complaints, but after reading the FAQs, I’m still a bit confused about where a question of this nature belongs.

**My Question**

Do  questions like this belong on Stack Overflow or Code Review? According to SO FAQ, It is a “a specific programming problem…”, but CR accepts “Security issues in a code snippet…”

My question is similar to [Which is the better fit -- Code Review or Stack Overflow?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/which-is-the-better-fit-code-review-or-stackoverflow) where Jeff answers, “Seems to me this question could go either way?”

Code Review is a wonderful idea and it’s still in its infancy, but overlap/crossover questions could lead to an “identity crisis” of sorts. Is there (or should there be) a *specific* place for these questions.

I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere. I searched this Meta, but found no definitive conclusion.

Answer (score 5):

As I see it, that particular question was not

> How can I improve this working code?

but

> Can anyone explain this working code to me.

A proper code review question is from someone who *already understands* functioning code, but wishes to improve upon it in some way...

Comment: +1 I can appreciate your point of view, but the OP clearly had an _idea_ and wanted to know if it was a _good idea_ or not. I'll concede that it may not be a prime example; nonetheless, **_my_** question is what to do with questions that actually "could go either way"?